# Is there any difference if I wrap a function inside another?

Tags: javascript, browserify

What is the difference between these two?
I import both in browserify and they seem to give the same result.
Is there any difference between them and how they work?

```
var App = (function () {
   var Foo = function (name) {
     this.name = name;
   };

   Foo.prototype.logout = function () {
     console.log();
   }

   return Foo;
})();

module.exports = App;
```

**VS**

```
var Foo = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
};

Foo.prototype.logout = function () {
  console.log();
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

Comment: It's helpful to others if you can think of a question title that is specific to your problem, with meaningful, relevant words. That way other people may find your question and helpful answers via a search.

Comment: i dont know what this stuff is called so its hard for me to say what i am comparing... a suggestion would be helpful...

Comment: Well the edit made to your original title is a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the only difference is that in the first code sample you end up with a variable named "App", and in the second you end up with one named "Foo". Other than that effect on the namespace, the two do the same thing.

More generally, code that looks like this:

```
var x = function() {
  // lots of stuff
  return something;
}();
```

allows for "lots of stuff" to be done in a context that's isolated from the surrounding context. That means that functions and variables defined inside that anonymous function won't "leak out" into the surrounding context unless that's an explicit goal of the `return` statement (or other code that otherwise affects some outer context somehow, most typically by direct modifications to `window` or something like the jQuery prototype).

In your example, again, the "lots of stuff" in the second example didn't involve altering any namespace other than that function prototype, which the first code does too.

Comment: the fact that the first one is wrapped in a function and auto runs doesnt matter? A coworker of mine told me the first one is a Factory and the second one isn't. Any idea on what they meant??

Comment: It makes them different in form, but not in effect. Once either piece of code has run, there'll be one symbol defined in the context of the code. In the first case, that symbol is "App"; in the second, it's "Foo".

Comment: @Sean answer updated with a little more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is difference between these two. First example keeps you safe from polluting your global scope with Foo variable, since it's wrapped in IFEE(Immediately Invoked Function Expressions) and assigned to variable App. Since Foo is inside IFEE it belongs to IFEE's scope. 
Foo variable from second example is in global scope and if you import this file in some other code Foo would override variable from that file if there also exist variable with that name. So to be sure that this wouldn't happen it's better to wrap imported code into IFEE.
Also, accessing variable Foo is different, in first example you would access it with App.Foo (since it's namespaced under App) and in second you access it with Foo.

Comment: But the first one equivalently pollutes the contextual scope with the "App" variable. Both pieces of code create exactly one symbol; the only difference is that one is called "App" and one is called "Foo".

Comment: Yes, you're right, question wasn't very clear so I was more referring to Foo behaviour.